# Unexpectedly high memory usage, using a std::stack and std::map

Tags: c++, memory, dictionary, stack, swap

I'm trying to traverse a tree, in order to visit all possible states of a 4x4 sliding puzzle. The algorithm I wrote was originally recursive, but this proved to be impossible due to the (apparently) very deep tree. It crashed and reported a segfault. I then decided to rewrite the algorithm to do its work iteratively, and from what I can see, it works just fine. However, after a while it starts to slow down tremendously due to swapping. I did some calculations, but can't figure out where all this memory usage is originating from...

The code is posted below, but here are the significant features:

- `std::stack<char, std::vector<char>> stack`
- `std::map<unsigned long long, int> distanceTable`

Assuming the memory footprint of the `stack` is proportional to the number of elements it holds, and assuming the same for the `map` (where an element is a `pair<unsigned long long, int>`), I printed out the expected memory footprint:

```
cout << (stack.size() * sizeof(char) +
         distanceTable.size() * sizeof(pair<unsigned long long, int>))/(1<<20) << "MB\n";
```

And compared the output to that of `top`. When my own program reported around 500MB, `top` reported that it was using over half of all my memory (4GB). This is a factor 4 that is unaccounted for by my reasoning. What am I missing here?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include "slider.h"
using namespace std;

typedef Slider<4> Slider4;
typedef Slider4::Move Move;
typedef map<unsigned long long, int> Map;
typedef stack<char, std::vector<char>> Stack;

Move const moves[] = {Slider4::N, Slider4::S, Slider4::E, Slider4::W};
Move const opposite[] = {Slider4::S, Slider4::N, Slider4::W, Slider4::E};

int const moveIdx[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
int const oppositeIdx[] = {1, 0, 3, 2};


Map generateDistanceTable()
{
    // non-recursive tree-walker to generate the distance-table
    Map distanceTable;
    Stack stack;
    Slider4 slider;
    unsigned long long depth = 1;

    stack.push(-1);
    distanceTable[slider.hash()]= depth;
    while (depth != 0)
    {
        cout << (stack.size() * sizeof(char) + 
                 distanceTable.size() * sizeof(pair<unsigned long long, int>))/(1ULL<<20) << "MB\n";

        int currentMove = stack.top() + 1;

        // find next move
        while (currentMove != 4)
        {
            // Try the move
            if (!slider.move(moves[currentMove]))
            {
                ++currentMove;
                continue;
            }

            // Check the current state of the puzzle
            auto &d = distanceTable[slider.hash()];
            if (d != 0)
            { // already encountered this state -> move back
                int undoMove = oppositeIdx[currentMove];
                slider.moveUnsafe(moves[undoMove]);
                ++currentMove; // try next move
                continue;
            } 

            stack.push(currentMove);
            d = ++depth;
            currentMove = 0;
        }

        if (currentMove == 4)
        {
            int undoMove = oppositeIdx[stack.top()];
            slider.moveUnsafe(moves[undoMove]);
            --depth;
            stack.pop();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Map table = generateDistanceTable();
}
```

Comment: You swapped the sizes in the output - is that just a copy&paste error, or is it in your code as well.

Comment: `distanceTable.size() * sizeof(char)` => how is this an accurate estimate of the map size? It has a constant factor difference from the actual size, which is exactly what you are reporting.

Comment: @Angew My bad, copy-paste error. Fixed it in the post, all reported results still valid.

Comment: You could use a [function](http://ideone.com/btzAIO) to prevent such errors ;-)

Comment: @Agnew Haha thanks for the tip ;-) I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: Also, note that a `std::map` will occupy around `N * sizeof(mapped_type) + N * log(N) * sizeof(key_type)` bytes.

Comment: @Angew That, I did not know... Oddly enough, this seems to overestimate the memory footprint.

Comment: @JorenHeit It might actually be `N * (log(N) - 1) * sizeof(key_type)`. The idea is that `std::map` is (most probably) a binary search tree. You could try `std::unordered_map` (most probably a hash table) instead, and see if it's more memory efficient in your case.

Comment: @Angew `std::map` is RB-tree, and I don't see its nodes' pointers taken into account (oh, and the color too -) )

Comment: @qwm Quite right, it's most likely an RB-tree (which is a BST). And you're right about the pointers, of course. I missed those. Bottom line: estimating memory footprints is messy & tricky business.

Comment: @Angew You beat me to it suggesting the `unordered_map`. I tried it and it gives me a factor 3 or so before the swapping starts again. Either the tree is really massive (upper bound on the puzzle is 16!), or my algorithm is wrong after all. Anyway, I'm gonna find someone with more memory than I have to see if they can do better! Thanks guys, I learned something today :-)

Comment: @Angew Where does the `log(N)`come from in your estimate? Binary trees have a linear size. Replacing std::map with either boost::flat_map or std::unordered_map is very often a win.

Comment: @JorenHeit, I'd look at the algorithm again. Depending on the time you want to spend on this, there are rotational and reflective symmetries to the 4x4 puzzle that should reduce the size of your search tree _significantly_.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Right you are, that's what I get for talking with my mind focused elsewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `std::map` is particularly inefficent with regards to
memory use.  Each value you insert will be placed in a separate
node, which in addition to the value, typically contains three
pointers and some additional information (2 `char` in the MS
implementation).  In addition, each node is typically allocated
separately, so the extra overhead needed by the allocator must
be added.  On a 32 bit system, the total overhead will be at
least 20 bytes; on a 64 bit system, 40.

As for `std::vector` (which underlies your `std::stack`), it is
much, much better, but if you don't use `reserve` to
pre-allocate, it will reallocate from time to time, usually
multiplying the capacity by 1.5 or 2.  Which means that it may
end up occupying a lot more memory than necessary.  (Also,
depending on the patterns of allocation, the system may not be
able to effectively reuse the memory freed during
a reallocation.)

Still, it's often preferrable to use an std::vector, kept in
order using `std::lower_bound`, instead of an `std::map`.

Finally, if you know in advance exactly how many entries the
vector will have, or can establish some reasonable upper bound,
you can use `reserve` to pre-allocate.  This avoids any risk of
doubling the size.

Comment: So it doesn't get lost from above, the `boost::flat_map` and `std::unordered_map` were also suggested as possible candidates for more memory-efficient containers.

Answer (score 1):

Each entry in the map must have at least an `unsigned long long` and an `int`. Most likely, it has two pointers as well (to hold the entries together).

```
distanceTable.size() * sizeof(char)
```

Should probably something like:

```
distanceTable.size() *
    (2 * sizeof (void *) + sizeof (unsigned long long ) + sizeof (int))
```

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I took that in account already. But if the preallocation scheme is smart, this effect will become less as the size increases. FYI, I use a `vector` under the hood.

Comment: A node in a map almost certainly has more than two pointers extra information.  I don't think linear iteration is possible without a parent pointer as well, in addition to left an right, and typical implementations use a red-black tree, which also requires information concerning the color.  (This can be hacked into the low order bit of the pointers, but the runtime cost for doing this is high.)  And of course, the nodes are dynamically allocated, which also adds to the cost.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here are nice, so I'll try taking a different tack: reduce the size of your game tree.

The wiki article on [game trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_tree) shows an example using Tic-Tac-Toe:

[image: Tic-Tac-Toe Game Tree]

Notice that since the board can be mirrored/reflected and rotated, there are, in fact, only 3 unique positions from which to begin the game. Depending on the type of problem you're trying to solve, you may be able to take advantage of similar possibilities.

Comment: Haha nice. I had of course already considered this. I'm aware that my implementation is a very naive one and obviously my next step is to take the rotation and mirror-symmetries into account. Thanks anyway for the suggestion!

Comment: It turns out that all mirror states are unreachable in the 15-puzzle. Nevertheless I got a factor 4 out of rotations. Just so you know ;-)